# HTML How to make input and image appear on same line

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to get a html input element and svg image to appear on the same line. Several suggested solutions exist on stackoverflow but I could not get any to work.

Current html code:

```
<div id = "inline_elements" style="width:100%">  
    <div class="data" id="text_data"><input type="text" width="48" height="48"/></div>
    <div class="svg_container">
        <svg id="svg_image" width="48" height="48"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
#svg_image {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.data {
    display: inline-block;
}

.svg_container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/bzu2x1vv/

I tried changing the following id fields but still image is located below input field:

```
.data {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.svg_result_container {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Your `jsfiddle` example shows them on the same line on my browser.

Comment: The fiddle has them on the same line for me in Firefox.

Comment: @guileria much appreciated, yes it works in jsfiddle but not in my webpage, must be other css inheritance causing an issue. I will close this question

Answer (score 0):

I cannot delete this question as it has an answer, but the code as is works to put the image in same line as the input field

Answer (score -1):

Create a parent div with 100% width in ur html. after that create a two child div in which the first child div have 50% width with float left and text align center property. the amother div contained image will have property like width 50% float right text -align center.

try this one and tell me.

Comment: I changed the .data and .svg_container elements as suggested. The image still appears below the input box

Comment: remove display-inline property and try it with only three properties.width float text-align for left and same for another width 50% float right text-align center

Comment: You need to give a property which you gave for .gg-input-filed to .data... then it will work. try this